# Group Theory For an algebraic system, how to prove the following?

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics, binary-operations, magma

I'm trying to prove the below equation

(From Elements of discrete mathematics, second edition by C. L. Liu
Question 11.13)

Let $(A, +)$ be an algebraic system such that for all $a, b$ in $A$ we have

$$(a + b) + a = a$$
$$(a + b) + b = (b + a) + a$$

(1) Show that $a + (a + b) = a + b$ for all $a$ and $b$

(2) Show that $а+a = (а+b) + (а+b)$ for all $a$ and $b$.

I got the 1st part as follows:

$(a+b)+a = a$

let $a+b = c$

Hence $c+a = a$

Now LHS of statement 1 is $a+(a+b)$.

Using a from (1) we get $c+a+c$

which is equivalent to $(c+a)+c $

c

a+b= RHS

How to prove the 2nd

Comment: What is it $a(a+b)$?

Comment: Show that $а+a = (а+b) + (а+b)$ - are there two different $a$'s?

Answer (score 4):

$$a+(a+b)=((a+b)+a)+(a+b)=a+b.$$
$$(a+b)+(a+b)=(a+(a+b))+(a+b)=((a+b)+a)+a=a+a.$$